# pyserial how to send µ

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

According to the [manual](http://www.kdscientific.com/downloads/KDS%20Literature/Manuals/KDS_Model_200_Manual.pdf) (page 15 and 16) for a pump from KD Scientific, I should send strings like `'voli 1000 µl \r\n'` to the pump in order to set the desired volume in microliters. However, pyserial gives me an error (`SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2'`) if I try to do so.

How can I send this command over the serial port ? I am using Python 2.7. Below a snapshot of the manual.

[image]

Comment: The µ is not an ASCII character, so, the docs should define the encoding to use. But just something you should try: often µ is just written as `u`.

Comment: Considering the age of that device (1998) I'm _guessing_ that it wants data encoded as  latin1 / cp-1252 rather than UTF-8. The latin1 encoding for µ is `\xb5`. So does `'voli 1000 \xb5l \r\n'` work?

Comment: I will give it a try

Comment: FWIW, you _can_ put non-ASCII characters like `µ` into your Python source, but you need to [declare the encoding](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) with a special comment at the top of your script. But it's probably simpler in this case to just use `\xb5`.

Comment: thats a good point, have to check that too

Answer (score 0):

This one is tricky. That manual does not say which encoding the device expects. We talk about RS232, so I expect it will want ASCII characters. However, μ is not a traditional ASCII character...

Here are a few shots in the dark for you to try:

1. Use `u` instead of `μ`. This is a common convention.
2. Try and play around with different encodings such as `'voli 1000 µl \r\n'.encode('utf-8')`

P.S. Sorry that this is not really an answer, but it's too long for a comment :)

Comment: I appreciate it. I will contact the company